# Sign into wifi network notification not appearing (captive portal, nginx)

Tags: wi-fi, internet, captive-portal

I'm using nginx to redirect all traffic to login.com (local server). And I want the sign into this wifi network message to appear. I searched for a long time and found out that android does a request to clients3.google.com/generate_204. If it redirects or returns something else than status code 204 is SHOULD display the login to wifi network message.

But with mine. It doesn't work. Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        location / {
                return 302 http://login.com;
        }
}
```

When I connect to my wifi network and go to a random website I get redirected to login.com. That works. If I go to a random-website.com/generate_204 it also gets redirected. And yes if I go to clients3.google.com/generate_204 it also gets redirected. But NO 'Sign into wifi network notification' appears.

I also tried not to redirect /generate_204 but instead use alias to display the login.com content but it didn't work.

From https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection

> If for any reason the web page is not returned, *or an HTTP response other than 204 is received*, then shill marks the service as **being in the portal state.**

I tried this but it didn't work. (also tried to return code 500 etc.)

What am I doing wrong? It should work because I saw it before.

Comment: Via e.g. `adb shell`, try `settings get global captive_portal_mode`. If that's set to something else than `1`, you've got your culprit. See: [Captive Portal parameters](/q/186993/16575)